# Print to log a core dump file stack, C++ over windows?

Tags: c++, windows, signals, coredump

When my process crashes, how can I print to log a core dump file stack, C++ over Windows?
I know that in Unix there is a way to do it using some signal handlers but never did it myself.
How can I do it in Windows (prefer not to use ACE)?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows equivalent of a core dump is called a Minidump, and you can write one using [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360.aspx).  There's an article about on codeproject here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/postmortemdebug_standalone1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own top level exception handler and walk the stack using dbghelp library to get a call stack. You may also generate an application crash dump [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696580/getting-a-dump-of-a-process-that-crashes-on-startup/700108#700108) way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a stack walker, take a look at [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx), created by Jochen Kalmbach. When run, it will let you log the stack trace in whatever way you like. The common way, however, is to ask Windows to create a dump (either full or mini).