# Win32: Is there a difference between Dr. Watson's full/mini dumps and writing my own?

Tags: c++, winapi, dump, crash-dumps

I have an application that is occasionally crashing in the release build; unfortunately, it looks like it is crashing in a 3rd party DLL.  While trying to get a handle on it I've been swimming in a sea of HOW TOs and descriptions of how Windows creates crash dumps.

I was thinking about using this suggested mini-dump:

[Getting a dump of a process that crashes on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696580/getting-a-dump-of-a-process-that-crashes-on-startup/700108#700108)

I was planning on leaving this functionality in the code so the dump is always created for my application without having to have the PC set up beforehand.  BTW, this application is not for distribution; it will be paired with our own hardware so I'm not concerned about random users having dump files building on their machines if the application happens to crash.

Additional note: all of the code is C/C++.

Is there a difference between what Dr. Watson (drwtsn32.exe) and this code will produce for me?

Answer (score 2):

With Dr. Watson you'll only get the dumps when the Dr. sees you 'crashed'. Using the dumper API you'll be able to invoke it from any point in the app. Eg. you can trampoline the ordinary asserts to dump instead of showing a dialog. In my experience once you have dump support in your app you'll find it easier down the road to investigate, troubleshoot and fix various problems, simply because you can produce a full dump (or even a minidump) at any place you see fit in code.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much difference except that if you create your own minidump you have more control over the level of detail in it.  By default Minidumps have the stack and some local variables, but creating your own gives you the option of creating a full memory dump also which may prove to be more useful (though this then may make collection of these dumps more problematic if the memory image is large).

If the crash happens reasonably frequently it may be worth just collecting some minidumps that drwatson (or werfault in Vista onwards) produces for you, as that may give you enough information.  If it doesn't then you have the option of adding your own unhandled exception filter.  Another thing that can happen is that the minidump you receive is the site of the crash rather than a first chance exception that may have arisen.  Creating your own minidumps means that you're more likely to get a stack trace closer to where the problem is.

Another option, if you have a machine which exhibits the problem more often is to run [ADPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) in the background -- it will sit and wait until your app crashes or throws exceptions then produce some useful log files.  It does a similar same thing as the unhandled exception filter except it requires no changes to your app.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing to watch out for is that [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360(VS.85).aspx) has to do memory allocation and file I/O.  Calling it from inside the failed process may fail if e.g. heap structures are corrupted.

Calling [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360(VS.85).aspx) from a helper process works the same as using Dr. Watson, except that you have control over the dump options.

Recommended reading: [loader lock deadlock in MiniDumpWriteDump](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windbg/browse_thread/thread/29c6bc03ea55f75e/986bef6d7fe8c742)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Although Dr Watson will generate full or mini dumps, you could use the [ntsd debugger instead](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX105888) to get a lot more control of what data is included in the dumps.

Dr Watson's minidumps are good enough for most things, you get a call stack and variables. IF you need more, [ntsd has a load of options](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/ntsdwatson.html).

The only benefit to using DrWatson is that is comes pre-installed on Windows.