# How to catch exe crashes from command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line, winapi

I'm doing batch-testing on our win32 c++ programs. Some of them crash. What's the best way to catch those crash from the command line and report it?

thanks

edit: answer:

1) you can't catch another process's exception from batch / command line

2) example to do it right in c#:

[How to handle a crash in a process launched via System.Diagnostics.Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673036/how-to-handle-a-crash-in-a-process-launched-via-system-diagnostics-process)

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a way of catching exceptions and crashes from the command line: use [ADPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) in crash mode and it will sit in the background listening for unhandled exceptions.

See also [Win32: Is there a difference between Dr. Watson's full/mini dumps and writing my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694701/win32-is-there-a-difference-between-dr-watsons-full-mini-dumps-and-writing-my/2694863#2694863)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe checking their return value in your script ? Of course, they have to adhere to a standard (for instance, in a unix-like os 0 = success, all else = error).

EDIT: also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

Comment: I can't because: 1) Visual Studio just-in-time debugger catches the crash and 2) my program doest return normally so i can't change the error code ( and i don't want to add a minidump catch )

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to catch,
1. Have a monitoring exe running as service or process.
2. Or implement crash class in windows 
may be usefull

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to add a minidump to my exes(2), so i guess i go for solution (1) and make a small launcher.exe

Comment: About solution (1)Do you have more info about capturing exception/crash from another process ?