# Best way to have crash dumps generated when processes crash?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, crash-dumps, drwatson

In `Windows` environments (`XP` and `Win 7`):

- What is the best way to automatically have a crash dump generated when processes crash on the system?
- Can an installer (MSI) package do this?

Comment: That's a global setting. Installers for a single program should definitely not alter global settings. If your program needs a crash dump, put the logic in your program.

Answer (score 17):

One of the best way to have an automatic dump for any/specific process on Windows is to configure a set of entries in the registry. I tried the below on Windows 7 64 bit.

Open notepad.exe, paste the below entry and save it as "EnableDump.reg". You can give any name you wish.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps]
"DumpFolder"=hex(2):44,00,3a,00,5c,00,64,00,75,00,6d,00,70,00,00,00
"DumpCount"=dword:00000010
"DumpType"=dword:00000002
"CustomDumpFlags"=dword:00000000
```

Double click the "EnableDump.reg" and select 'Yes'. I have given the dump folder as 'd:\dump'. You can change it to whatever folder you wish. e.g.

> 'c:\dump' = `43,00,3a,00,5c,00,64,00,75,00,6d,00,70,00,00,00`

Try to execute a crashing application, Windows will display the error dialog. Choose 'Close the Program' option. After that you will see the dump in the configured folder. The name of the dump file will be .exe..dmp.

For more details, you can refer the below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Just have a try on XP. You can write a c++ console application and paste the code below.


int main( void )
{

 char *pp;
 char* tpp;
 strncpy( pp, tpp, 5000 );
 return 0;
}


Run the app, it will crash. Close the Windows Error Dialog. Check the configured folder for dump file.

Comment: As per the Microsoft documentation, it works starting from below platform only.  

Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 (SP1).

Comment: Yes, divide by zero will work provided you unmask the floating point exception for divide by zero. By default, the run-time library will mask all the floating point exceptions.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working on WIndows 7 Enterprise 64bit

Comment: @IgorMesaros: Its working fine on Windows 7 Professional 64bit. AFAIK, Enterprise edition doesn't make any difference in this case.

Comment: `CustomDumpFlags` seems to be used only when `DumpType` is set to 0 (Custom dump).  If using `DumpType` 2 (Full dump), then `CustomDumpFlags` does not needed to be set.

Answer (score 4):

> Below explanation is based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700108/8740349), but the logic is mine (without attribution need, as said on my profile);

Having your own dump generation framework which automatically creates a process dump when any Unhandled exception is encountered, would avoid clients having to install `WinDbg`.

At the application start up use `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(...)` Win32 API to register a callback (i.e. application level exception-handler).
Now the registered callback function is called whenever there is any exception which is not handled. You may then create the process dump using `MiniDumpWriteDump(...)` API from `DbgHelp.dll`.

### C++ Sample <sup>(unicode-enabled)</sup>

### header-file

```cpp
#ifndef CRASH_REPORTER_H
#define CRASH_REPORTER_H

//Exclude rarely used content from the Windows headers.
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#    define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#    include <windows.h>
#    undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#else
#    include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <tchar.h>
#include <DbgHelp.h>

class CrashReporter {
public:
    inline CrashReporter() { Register(); }
    inline ~CrashReporter() { Unregister(); }

    inline static void Register() {
        if(m_lastExceptionFilter != NULL) {
            fprintf(stdout, "CrashReporter: is already registered\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
        //ensures UnHandledExceptionFilter is called before App dies.
        m_lastExceptionFilter = SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(UnHandledExceptionFilter);
    }
    inline static void Unregister() {
        SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(m_lastExceptionFilter);
    }

private:
    static LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER m_lastExceptionFilter;
    static LONG WINAPI UnHandledExceptionFilter(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS *);
};


#endif // CRASH_REPORTER_H
```

### source-file

```cpp
#include "crash-report.h"

#include <stdio.h>

LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER CrashReporter::m_lastExceptionFilter = NULL;

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *MiniDumpWriteDumpFunc)(HANDLE hProcess, DWORD ProcessId
        , HANDLE hFile
        , MINIDUMP_TYPE DumpType
        , const MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION *ExceptionInfo
        , const MINIDUMP_USER_STREAM_INFORMATION *UserStreamInfo
        , const MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INFORMATION *Callback
    );

LONG WINAPI CrashReporter::UnHandledExceptionFilter(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *exceptionPtr)
{
    //we load DbgHelp.dll dynamically, to support Windows 2000
    HMODULE hModule = ::LoadLibraryA("DbgHelp.dll");
    if (hModule) {
        MiniDumpWriteDumpFunc dumpFunc = reinterpret_cast<MiniDumpWriteDumpFunc>(
                    ::GetProcAddress(hModule, "MiniDumpWriteDump")
                );
        if (dumpFunc) {
            //fetch system time for dump-file name
            SYSTEMTIME  SystemTime;
            ::GetLocalTime(&SystemTime);
            //choose proper path for dump-file
            wchar_t dumpFilePath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
            _snwprintf_s(dumpFilePath, MAX_PATH, L"crash_%04d-%d-%02d_%d-%02d-%02d.dmp"
                    , SystemTime.wYear, SystemTime.wMonth, SystemTime.wDay
                    , SystemTime.wHour, SystemTime.wMinute, SystemTime.wSecond
                );
            //create and open the dump-file
            HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFileW( dumpFilePath, GENERIC_WRITE
                    , FILE_SHARE_WRITE
                    , NULL
                    , CREATE_ALWAYS
                    , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
                    , NULL
                );

            if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                _MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION exceptionInfo;
                exceptionInfo.ThreadId          = GetCurrentThreadId();
                exceptionInfo.ExceptionPointers = exceptionPtr;
                exceptionInfo.ClientPointers    = NULL;
                //at last write crash-dump to file
                bool ok = dumpFunc(::GetCurrentProcess(), ::GetCurrentProcessId()
                        , hFile, MiniDumpNormal
                        , &exceptionInfo, NULL, NULL
                    );
                //dump-data is written, and we can close the file
                CloseHandle(hFile);
                if (ok) {
                    //Return from UnhandledExceptionFilter and execute the associated exception handler.
                    //  This usually results in process termination.
                    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Proceed with normal execution of UnhandledExceptionFilter.
    //  That means obeying the SetErrorMode flags,
    //  or invoking the Application Error pop-up message box.
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}
```

#### usage

```
#include "3rdParty/crash-report.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CrashReporter crashReporter;
    (void)crashReporter; //prevents unused warnings

    // [application main loop should be here]

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP:
The following steps enable automatic crash dumps:

```
1) Open a command prompt, running as administrator
2) Run drwtsn32 -i. This will install Doctor Watson as the default debugger when something crashes
3) Click Ok
4) From the command prompt, run drwtsn32
5) Set the Crash Dump path to your favorite directory, or leave the default.
6) Set the Crash Dump Type to mini. Note that under some circumstances, we may ask you for a full crash dump.
7) Make sure the Dump All Thread Contexts and Create Crash Dump File options are selected.
8) Click Ok
9) If a user.dmp file already exists in the Crash Dump path, delete it.
```

Windows 7: Location is:

```
C:\Users[Current User when app crashed]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive
```

Comment: Can an MSI package apply this configuration?

Comment: In what context? Are you looking to get your program to dump errors?

Comment: Yes, I want crashes to generate crash dumps. It might be a registry change that an MSI installer could apply.

Comment: Are you referring to all crashed processes or a process/program you have developed?

Comment: I would like to generate crash dumps for my programs.

Comment: What is the reason for Step 9 in the instructions for XP?  Won't the `user.dmp` be overwritten anyway?

Comment: Is it also necessary to have `drwatson.exe` running on the machine for the crash dumps to be generated?

Comment: Step9, have you made any attempt to do the setup, that way you will see some other options that would answer this step?

Comment: What attempts have you made since suggestions where recommended?

Comment: I followed the above instuctions for XP. The users reported that the application had crashed.  I looked at the user.dmp file and it was quite old.

Comment: First take a look at this [step](http://support.emsisoft.com/topic/3810-how-to-configure-automatic-crash-dumps-in-case-of-application-failures/) and confirm thats what you have. Also is this application an in-house app or a 3rd party application?

Comment: That is the configuration I have. This is just an application installed on a customer's machine.