# Create crash dump report for a C++ application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Sometimes it happens that your distributed application crashes on customer machines. What you obtain as an info from the customer is that the application simply crashed "doing something": no way to understand where the bug was in your code. Is there a library/add-on to be linked to your application that can create a backtrace file/crash dump report so that it could be sent by the customer to better understand what you normally see in the Visual Studio call stack helping understanding where the bug is?

Comment: All versions of Windows starting from XP. The C++ application is compiled in release mode

Comment: Fix the tags of your question then.

Comment: Post-Mortem Debugging: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1934/Post-Mortem-Debugging-Your-Application-with-Minidu

Comment: there is a simple way to create crush dump files see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211155/8740349

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see google: https://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/

Description from the website:

Breakpad is a library and tool suite that allows you to distribute an application to users with compiler-provided debugging information removed, record crashes in compact "minidump" files, send them back to your server, and produce C and C++ stack traces from these minidumps. Breakpad can also write minidumps on request for programs that have not crashed.

https://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/wiki/GettingStartedWithBreakpad

Answer (score 2):

There are a few third party solutions available that provide a library of functions to trap crash data.  A simple google search should suffice.  However, depending on your budget, the easiest solution is to create a Microsoft [WER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513613(v=vs.85).aspx) account.  WER has advantages over the other solutions because it is part of the OS and it exposes several functions that allow you to tailor the crash data collection.