# Get crash dumps from user when program crashes

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, debugging, crash

When a program crashes it will usually create three files with information on the crash. Once these files generate Windows will usually ask if you want to send the files to them. After closing this dialog the three crash dumps are deleted.

I am developing a program in Visual Studio 2015 using C#/WPF and I would like to know if there was a way to save the dumps in a more convenient location so when users of my application do experience a crash they can send me the dumps so I can check the situation.

On Windows 7 and 10 (I'd assume 8 as well) the files generate in 'user'\appdata\local\temp and as I said they are deleted the moment the dialog is clicked away. I saw a solution here([Best way to have crash dumps generated when processes crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237201/best-way-to-have-crash-dumps-generated-when-processes-crash)) that could work but if possible I only want to move crash dumps coming from my program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's anyway to build into your program so that the crash dumps are saved in a custom location if that's what you're asking. However, I used to work in support, and I found that [Procdump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) is very user friendly (read: easy to get a user to set up without botching it :)), allows you to monitor crashes/hangs from only your process and save the corresponding dumps in the location of your choice.

You can also do a simple .bat script to have it start up upon user login in case your user reboots.