# Windows stop creating dump when click on crashed application

Tags: c#, .net, crash-dumps

I set registry values to make a crash dump (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237201/best-way-to-have-crash-dumps-generated-when-processes-crash)).

It works great for small applications (few megabytes).

When my application is huge, almost 2GB in ram memory and when it crashes, the dump file is created in specified directory.
During dump creation application is in 'frozen state'. When user click on this frozen application, system stops creating dump, and remove active dump file from dump directory.

Have anyone idea how can I prevent this situation?

Comment: It's not enough to click on the non-responding application. The user must also select the button to kill the application.

Answer (score 1):

There are two Registry entries that influence the behavior: 
[HungAppTimeout (MS Technet)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978614.aspx)
and [WaitToKillAppTimeout (MS Technet)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978624.aspx).

Another approach is the per-application setting [DisableProcessWindowsGhosting (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648415%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This requires some modification in your code: calls that method to prevent window dimming. This will affect all users.

If you don't want to change it in your code, you can apply the same setting with the "NoGhost" option of [Application Compatibility Toolkit (MS Technet)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows//aa905066.aspx). This can be done on a per PC basis.

Comment: I will be able to check if it works in our system in next week and I'll let you know about results.

Comment: @LukTar: I added more options. See the updated answer.