# Is replacing all standard error-dialogs with debug-breaks or error-throws possible?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, error-handling, dump

**I would like to replace any standard error-dialog with `throw` or `debug-break`** (with standard I mean anything which is not explicitly written by me) since like in the reason-section described, it would cause debugging of a Windows-Service sometimes to be impossible.

to accomplish this I did try defining something like:

```
-D "_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0"
```

but above did just disable the error-dialogs and is really not enough to track down the issues, so I would like it to `throw-exception` or to `debug-break` instead of showing the error-dialog.

is there anything else you would suggest me to define or do?

### Reason:

While developing a Windows-Service, I had some hard times to find a bug which was causing the server to crash:

- there was an [Off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) error in `std::unordered_map` usage
- the App's [crash-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211155/8740349) feature was prevented by `std::unordered_map` which tried to show an error message-box (since compiled in debug-mode)
- but the program did crash without giving any feedback, basically because a windows-service is not allowed to show any error-dialog (except by using "[WTSSendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtssendmessagea)(...)")
- even when the debugger was attached, still nothing...
- Only using `git` history and rechecking all recent changes was it possible to find the issue

### Reproduce:

by running below in a service (compiled in debug-mode) you can reproduce this issue:

```
#include <unordered_map>

// will cause crash by trying to increment iterator pointing to end
inline static void simulateCrash() {
    typedef std::unordered_map<quint32, quint32> Hash;
    Hash list;
    list[0xC001] = 0xDEAD;
    Hash::iterator it = list.begin();
    it = list.erase(it);
    ++it; // should crash here
}
```

Comment: Do you compile in release or debug ? `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` is compiler specific BTW, you would have `NDEBUG` which is standard (for `assert`)...

Comment: _"the App's crash-dump feature was prevented by std::unordered_map which tried to show a message-box"_ <-- this is suspicious.

Comment: BTW, UB would not necessary crash (or crash the way expected by your crash-dump).

Comment: your guess is right I was compiling in debug mode while trying to fix the issue, but I want to disable any error-dialog even when compiling in debug mode since that is not allowed in Windows-Service anyway...

Comment: @Jarod42, I have edited the question, since indeed disabling the error-dialog did just hide the issue from our view (since it did not cause any crash or exception-throw)

Comment: So you might customize error handler as I suggest in my answer. if you throw from the handler (which is a C-function, you probably need to change also some build option (`/EH`)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use [`_set_invalid_parameter_handler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-invalid-parameter-handler-set-thread-local-invalid-parameter-handler?view=vs-2017) to overwrite default handler which terminates the program and displays a runtime error message.

[`_CrtSetReportMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportmode?view=vs-2017) is also useful to avoid dialog from `_CrtDbgReport` (used in several checks).

Comment: thanks, by using `_set_invalid_parameter_handler` (with a custom-handler which throws an exception) and undoing my changes to `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` macro, at last the crash-dump does work !!!

Comment: at the time that the issue happened we were unable to attach any debugger anyway (so crash-dump was our only option)