# Sideloaded app crashes for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I installed my app using a sideloaded package on 2 different computer.

The app is installing, with the certificate and the Powershell script, but once it's installed when I try to launch it, the app is crashing instantly for no reason.

I installed the app on the laptop I used to develop the app, and it's working properly so I don't know why it's crashing on others devices.

Is there any way to get the logs of installed UWP apps to know why it is doing that ?

**Edit** :
Crash minidump in WinDbg

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.18869.1002 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\furio\AppData\Local\CrashDumps\BasePosteMobilite.exe.392.dmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 17763 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Sun May 19 23:14:52.000 2019 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:01.000
................................................................
...........................
Loading unloaded module list
.....
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(188.16a0): Unknown exception - code c000027b (first/second chance not available)
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0xaf:
00007ff8`5fbadbff 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
0:008> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for BasePosteMobilite.dll

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.Sec
    Value: 1

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.Sec
    Value: 2

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 248

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 1


PROCESSES_ANALYSIS: 1

SERVICE_ANALYSIS: 1

STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1

Timeline: !analyze.Start
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2019-05-20T05:05:47.160Z
    Diff: 28255160 mSec

Timeline: Dump.Current
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2019-05-19T21:14:52.0Z
    Diff: 0 mSec

Timeline: Process.Start
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2019-05-19T21:14:51.0Z
    Diff: 1000 mSec


DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

MODLIST_WITH_TSCHKSUM_HASH:  fcc2982da99dc8e2448646a272094c2c4749abd2

MODLIST_SHA1_HASH:  953d163b504bcee37a2ae89f5d7843dd318bd69d

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

DUMP_FLAGS:  94

DUMP_TYPE:  1

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=000000d8498fe450 rbx=000000d8498fea00 rcx=000000d8498fe450
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000002 rdi=000000d8498fe450
rip=00007ff85fbadbff rsp=000000d8498fe370 rbp=000000d8498fea40
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=000000d8498fea00 r12=0000000000000004 r13=00007ff85588e000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000244
KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0xaf:
00007ff8`5fbadbff 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
Resetting default scope

FAULTING_IP: 
Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+3e012
00007ff8`4bc17842 488d4c2420      lea     rcx,[rsp+20h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ff84bc17842 (Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+0x000000000003e012)
   ExceptionCode: c000027b
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 000002d1a1eb6380
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000002

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STOWED_EXCEPTION

PROCESS_NAME:  BasePosteMobilite.exe

BUGCHECK_STR:  STOWED_EXCEPTION

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000027b - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000027b - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c000027b

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  000002d1a1eb6380

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000002

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  5ce1c3a4

WATSON_BKT_PROCVER:  1.0.0.0

WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll

WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP:  155de37a

WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET:  707842

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  10.0.17763.404

MODULE_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-8BF0GSN

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  05-20-2019 07:05:47.0160

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18869.1002 amd64fre

MANAGED_CODE: 1

MANAGED_ENGINE_MODULE:  mrt100

MANAGED_ANALYSIS_PROVIDER:  MRT

MANAGED_THREAD_ID: 16a0

MANAGED_EXCEPTION_ADDRESS: ffffffffffffffff

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
OS_LOCALE:  FRA

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STOWED_EXCEPTION

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

    ID:     [0n258]
    Type:   [STOWED_EXCEPTION]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [Unspecified]
    Frame:  [0]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00007ff8629a5450 to 00007ff85fbadbff

STACK_TEXT:  
000000d8`498fe370 00007ff8`629a5450 : 000002d1`85cfd6c8 00007ff8`62a9a540 000002d1`85cfd6c8 00007ff8`62a9a540 : KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0xaf
000000d8`498fe940 00007ff8`4bc17842 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 000002d1`a1f8df30 00000000`00000000 : combase!RoFailFastWithErrorContextInternal2+0x480
000000d8`498fec20 00007ff8`4bc1720a : 00000000`00000000 000000d8`498fecd0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+0x3e012
000000d8`498fec70 00007ff8`4bc17099 : 000002d1`a1f756f0 ffffffff`ffffff00 00000000`00000000 000002d1`a1f75740 : Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+0x3d9da
000000d8`498fecf0 00007ff8`5d2d2f32 : 00000000`00000002 00007ff8`6281314f ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+0x3d869
000000d8`498fed20 00007ff8`5d2d2f8a : 000002d1`85c97b40 000002d1`a1f756f0 000002d1`85c75158 00007ff8`5d27d2f7 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::Internal::Details::GitInvokeHelper<Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>,Windows::Internal::GitPtr,2>::Invoke+0x62
000000d8`498fed60 00007ff8`5d2c28e3 : 000002d1`a1f75740 00000000`00000000 000000d8`498fee50 00007ff8`5d27ca62 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorInvokeHelper::Invoke+0x1a
000000d8`498fed90 00007ff8`5d2c2279 : 000002d1`85ca15c0 000000d8`498fee60 000000d8`498fee50 000000d8`498feee8 : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::InvokeTraits<2>::InvokeDelegates<<lambda_554db31ac46423117fe731f412dd63d8>,Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64> >+0x57
000000d8`498fede0 00007ff8`5d2c2880 : ffffffff`fffffffe 000002d1`85cfd6c8 000002d1`85ca15c0 00007ff8`5d2c3977 : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::EventSource<Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>,Microsoft::WRL::InvokeModeOptions<2> >::DoInvoke<<lambda_554db31ac46423117fe731f412dd63d8> >+0x65
000000d8`498fee30 00007ff8`5d2cd52a : 00000000`00000000 000002d1`85cfd6c8 000002d1`a1f756f0 00007ff8`62b6d5a5 : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::EventSource<Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>,Microsoft::WRL::InvokeModeOptions<2> >::InvokeAll<std::nullptr_t,Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>+0x34
000000d8`498fee80 00007ff8`5d2e7781 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000002d1`a1f756f0 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::ForwardLocalError+0x6a
000000d8`498feed0 00007ff8`629a3fa3 : 00000000`00000000 000002d1`85cfd6c8 000002d1`85c74d50 00000000`00000001 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationFactory::ForwardLocalError+0xf1
000000d8`498fef10 00007ff8`26e98f0c : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ff8`0fe59ae0 000002d1`85f405f8 : combase!CallErrorForwarder+0x12f
000000d8`498fefa0 00007ff8`26f31ed9 : 000002d1`85eed460 00000000`00000000 000002d1`85f40328 00007ff8`26cd374d : SharedLibrary!$8_System::Runtime::InteropServices::ExceptionHelpers.ReportUnhandledError+0xbc
000000d8`498ff080 00007ff8`102c270d : 000002d1`85f40328 000002d1`85ee9e98 000002d1`85d16aa0 00007ff8`0fe59ae0 : SharedLibrary!$8_Internal::Interop::InteropCallbacks.ReportUnhandledError+0x9
000000d8`498ff0b0 000002d1`85f40328 : 000002d1`85ee9e98 000002d1`85d16aa0 00007ff8`0fe59ae0 000002d1`85eed460 : BasePosteMobilite+0x298270d
000000d8`498ff0b8 000002d1`85ee9e98 : 000002d1`85d16aa0 00007ff8`0fe59ae0 000002d1`85eed460 00007ff8`26ce11fb : 0x000002d1`85f40328
000000d8`498ff0c0 000002d1`85d16aa0 : 00007ff8`0fe59ae0 000002d1`85eed460 00007ff8`26ce11fb 00000000`00000000 : 0x000002d1`85ee9e98
000000d8`498ff0c8 00007ff8`0fe59ae0 : 000002d1`85eed460 00007ff8`26ce11fb 00000000`00000000 000000d8`498ff1d0 : 0x000002d1`85d16aa0
000000d8`498ff0d0 000002d1`85eed460 : 00007ff8`26ce11fb 00000000`00000000 000000d8`498ff1d0 00007ff8`269fca68 : BasePosteMobilite+0x2519ae0
000000d8`498ff0d8 00007ff8`26ce11fb : 00000000`00000000 000000d8`498ff1d0 00007ff8`269fca68 00007ff8`4f6464c4 : 0x000002d1`85eed460
000000d8`498ff0e0 00007ff8`26ce11c9 : 000023cb`00000002 00000000`00000005 00000001`ffffffff 00000002`00000000 : SharedLibrary!System::RuntimeExceptionHelpers.ReportUnhandledException+0x2b
000000d8`498ff120 00007ff8`26d790e5 : 00000000`00011000 000002d1`00000000 00000000`000b0bff 000000d8`498ff588 : SharedLibrary!Internal::Runtime::Augments::RuntimeAugments.ReportUnhandledException+0x9
000000d8`498ff150 00007ff8`4f635efb : 00007ff8`269fca5b 00007ff8`4f64613d 000002d1`85c1c214 00007ff8`00000033 : SharedLibrary!System::Threading::WinRTSynchronizationContext::Invoker.InvokeCore$catch$0+0xd
000000d8`498ff180 00007ff8`4f62f02e : 000002d1`85eed460 00007ff8`26d790d8 000000d8`498ff450 000000d8`498ff410 : mrt100_app!RhpCallCatchFunclet+0x15b
000000d8`498ff2a0 00007ff8`4f62f569 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000080 000002d1`ffffffff 00000000`85c7ef70 : mrt100_app!RhRethrow+0x4ae
000000d8`498ff3c0 00007ff8`4f635ca7 : 000002d1`85c7a8c8 00000000`00000000 000002d1`85c962e8 ffffffff`00000001 : mrt100_app!RhThrowEx+0x49
000000d8`498ff3f0 00007ff8`26cdd932 : 00000000`00000002 000000d8`498ffb18 000002d1`85c87701 000000d8`498ffae0 : mrt100_app!RhpThrowEx+0x117
000000d8`498ff780 00007ff8`26d9849f : 000000d8`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ff8`5cc99f00 00000000`00000000 : SharedLibrary!System::Runtime::ExceptionServices::ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw+0x22
000000d8`498ff7b0 00007ff8`26b89499 : 00000000`ffffffff 00007ff8`624c6e4f 000002d1`85c1d240 00000087`e130dcbf : SharedLibrary!System::Runtime::CompilerServices::AsyncMethodBuilderCore::<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0+0x1f
000000d8`498ff7e0 00007ff8`26d790c4 : 00000000`00000000 000002d1`85d16aa0 00007ff8`2654cd80 00007ff8`4f62d7da : SharedLibrary!System::Func$2<System::__Canon,System::TimeSpan>.Invoke+0x29
000000d8`498ff810 00007ff8`26d7907c : 00000000`00000000 000002d1`85d19558 00000000`00000000 00000000`80000012 : SharedLibrary!System::Threading::WinRTSynchronizationContext::Invoker.InvokeCore+0x34
000000d8`498ff860 00007ff8`26b893c2 : 00000000`000003a8 00000000`000002f4 00000000`00000300 00000000`00000304 : SharedLibrary!System::Threading::WinRTSynchronizationContext::Invoker.Invoke+0x1c
000000d8`498ff890 00007ff8`1028b1de : 000002d1`85d06dc8 00007ff8`26d4cd81 00000000`00000000 00007ff8`62528070 : SharedLibrary!System::Action$1<System::__Canon>.InvokeOpenStaticThunk+0x22
000000d8`498ff8c0 000002d1`85d06dc8 : 00007ff8`26d4cd81 00000000`00000000 00007ff8`62528070 00000000`00000000 : BasePosteMobilite+0x294b1de
000000d8`498ff8c8 00007ff8`26d4cd81 : 00000000`00000000 00007ff8`62528070 00000000`00000000 00007ff8`0fe59b46 : 0x000002d1`85d06dc8
000000d8`498ff8d0 00007ff8`26d4f5bd : ffffffff`ffffffff 00007ff8`624ac939 0000d6d7`823a5a84 00007ff8`0fe4923d : SharedLibrary!$8_System::Runtime::InteropServices::__native_ccw.get_ComCallableObject+0x11
000000d8`498ff900 00007ff8`26ed6349 : 000002d1`85d06d20 00007ff8`5578e178 000002d1`00000000 00000000`00000000 : SharedLibrary!$8_System::Runtime::InteropServices::ComCallableObject.GetTarget+0xd
000000d8`498ff930 00007ff8`0fe59b09 : 000002d1`85d19558 00007ff8`00000002 000000d8`498ffb51 00000000`00000000 : SharedLibrary!$8_System::Runtime::InteropServices::McgMarshal.ThisPointerToTargetObject+0x9
000000d8`498ff960 000002d1`85d19558 : 00007ff8`00000002 000000d8`498ffb51 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff : BasePosteMobilite+0x2519b09
000000d8`498ff968 00007ff8`00000002 : 000000d8`498ffb51 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff 000002d1`85c6a460 : 0x000002d1`85d19558
000000d8`498ff970 000000d8`498ffb51 : 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff 000002d1`85c6a460 000002d1`85d06d20 : 0x00007ff8`00000002
000000d8`498ff978 00000000`00000000 : ffffffff`ffffffff 000002d1`85c6a460 000002d1`85d06d20 00007ff8`55785614 : 0x000000d8`498ffb51


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  8755e398dbb50ac67be3ca4547ecb5f59fc2bb5a

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  725654bfd75090a038ec37d9131a8b274703cc6e

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  f831ba210ee6a79d080461f490281e9647047f1d

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+3e012
00007ff8`4bc17842 488d4c2420      lea     rcx,[rsp+20h]

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  244c8d48

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+3e012

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Windows_UI_Xaml

IMAGE_NAME:  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  155de37a

STACK_COMMAND:  ~8s ; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  STOWED_EXCEPTION_Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+3e012

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  c000027b

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll

FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  Windows_UI_Xaml

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  Windows_UI_Xaml

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  GetStringRawBuffer

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  GetStringRawBuffer

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  3e012

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  155de37a

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  10c10ac

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  10.0.17763.404

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  STOWED_EXCEPTION_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STOWED_EXCEPTION

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!GetStringRawBuffer

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  STOWED_EXCEPTION_c000027b_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!GetStringRawBuffer

TARGET_TIME:  2019-05-19T21:14:52.000Z

OSBUILD:  17763

OSSERVICEPACK:  475

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  256

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt SingleUserTS

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  1989-09-10 08:58:46

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  180914-1434

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs5_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  a71

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:stowed_exception_c000027b_windows.ui.xaml.dll!getstringrawbuffer

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {6fe7fa9e-4591-e5ee-47b7-18aaeaea9c02}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Also, I've installed Visual Studio on my other pc and when I'm launching the app I'm getting an exception at `InitializeComponent()` line saying `Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException` but I don't get why.

**Edit 2** : 
The Xaml file which gives me the exception

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="BasePosteMobilite.Views.ShellPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:winui="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:helpers="using:BasePosteMobilite.Helpers"
    xmlns:ic="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:behaviors="using:BasePosteMobilite.Behaviors"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
            <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.LoadedCommand}" />
        </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>


    <winui:NavigationView
        x:Name="navigationView"
        IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
        IsBackEnabled="False"
        SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
        IsSettingsVisible="False"
        Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}" PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact" IsPaneOpen="False">
        <winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <!--
            TODO WTS: Change the symbols for each item as appropriate for your app
            More on Segoe UI Symbol icons: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font
            Or to use an IconElement instead of a Symbol see https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/blob/master/docs/projectTypes/navigationpane.md
            Edit String/en-US/Resources.resw: Add a menu item title for each page
            -->
            <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Name="navInfosPoste" x:Uid="Shell_InfosPoste" Icon="PreviewLink" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="BasePosteMobilite.ViewModels.InfosPosteViewModel" Content="Informations FIP" />
            <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Name="navPlanHTA" x:Uid="Shell_PlanHTA" Icon="Map" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="BasePosteMobilite.ViewModels.PlanHTAViewModel" Content="Plan HTA"/>
        </winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior
                DefaultHeader="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected.Content, Mode=OneWay}">
                <behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.DefaultHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding}"
                                Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                                Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.DefaultHeaderTemplate>
            </behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior>
            <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemInvoked">
                <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemInvokedCommand}" />
            </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Grid>
            <Frame x:Name="shellFrame" />
        </Grid>
        <winui:NavigationView.PaneFooter>
            <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Settings" Icon="Setting" Content="Paramètres " Tapped="NavigationViewItem_Tapped"/>
        </winui:NavigationView.PaneFooter>
    </winui:NavigationView>
</Page>
```

Comment: Can you look at the crash minidumps?   Can you add some logging of your own to a text file to see if loading reaches the point where your code starts to run?

Comment: Where can I find these crash minidumps ?

Comment: You might need to enable them first - https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/kb/how-to-generate-crash-dump-on-windows-machine.html  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237201/best-way-to-have-crash-dumps-generated-when-processes-crash or search "application crash dump location"

Comment: Ok got it, I've edited the post.

Comment: Could you share a [mcve]